# JVMXM008: Error occured while initialising System ClassException in thread "main" Could not create the Java virtual machine

Tags: java, aix

I am unable to execute the java command in a specific folder , throwing error as below

```
JVMXM008: Error occured while initialising System ClassException in thread "main" Could not create the Java virtual machine.
```

With same user, I am able to run java in home directory but I am not able to run in application config directory.

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/java14

java -version
java version "1.4.2"
Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.4.2)
Classic VM (build 1.4.2, J2RE 1.4.2 IBM AIX build ca142-20080515 (SR11) (JIT enabled: jitc))
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you do not have appropriate permissions in the 'specific folder' to access resources needed to start the JVM.  You either need to get permissions(preferred) or run as root.